# c++ - getline( ) reads entire text file on MAC and partial on Window 7;

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, ifstream, getline

I have a c++ program.

Purpose of program is to open and print txt file from directory.

```
stringstream dir;

dir << "path goes here";


std::ifstream t(dir.str());
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

cout << str << endl;
```

When I compile on a MAC the cout << str prints out the whole file. When I do it on a windows only about half of it.

I have tried different read in methods such as getline() and they all have the same problem

MAC: xcode 5
Windows Visual Studio Express 2010

Thank you

Comment: Probably contains a <ctrl>-Z, which Windows interprets as end of file. Try opening like: `std::ifstream t(dir.str(), std::binary)` and see if that helps.

Comment: What does the file look like where it is cut off on windows?

Comment: and it's in case anyone couldn't get it to work std::ifstream t(dir.str(), std::ios::binary)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Read the whole file into a std::string?

Comment: yes I just wanted to open a txt file into a string